# PHP: codecomments inside functions prevents it work

Tags: php

```
$query = $connect->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");

$query->execute();

$row = $query->fetch();

// $full_name = $row["firstname"] . " ".$row["lastname"];

$full_name = $row["firstname"] . " ".substr($row["lastname"], 0, 1).".";

return $full_name;
```

If i remove the line that is a comment ( // ), it will return $full_name, if its there then it wont work. I also tried commenting with #, but it still wont work(wont return anything) as soon as there is a codecomment

weird issue

Comment: the only thing i can think of is the speech marks may be screwing it up? Ie. its stopping the comment halfway through the line

Comment: Are you getting an error? How is your file executed? Are you using some kind of compiler/minifier which would remove all the new lines? In that case your comments would get all the remain of the function also commented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has never happend to me.. very strange.

Try to add some text after `//` or put everything between this another kind of comment a code

`/* the code */`

Comment: This works, I do not know why but when i comment within the /* and */ it return and execute just fine.. Accepted, but still wants to know why exactly that it didnt work with # or // (as i always use)

Comment: Good it works for you. Perheaps something in your php.ini file or even in your httpd.conf apache confoguration file.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think if it's really the code: check the newline character settings in your editor or try to open it in another editor. Maybe the php parser see it in one line.
But I dont think so.

Comment: +1 (similar to regilero...) I think the parser sees line breaks that the editor does not.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment shouldn't have any effect on the execution.

Have you tried turning on all the error handling? What are the contents for var_dump($row); ?

Comment: Yes there is the right vars in the $row array. It do affect the execution, very very weird. I have also tried to do // hallo and then it still wont execute the return/doesnt return anything. but when i remove it works.

Answer (score 1):

This should be basic debugging (as well as a literal sanity check), however I'll post it as an answer; First of all turn all errors on, then:

```
echo 'before: ' . $full_name;
// $full_name = $row["firstname"] . " ".$row["lastname"];
echo 'after' . $full_name;
```

**I do realise this is insane! A comment is a comment and will never have any effect on your output.**

Both `echo`s should trigger a warning since there is no `$full_name` variable defined yet; However, if both are printed you'll know (as we all know) the problem isn't the comment itself... (At this point, my guess is that `$full_name = " ";` because `$query->fetch();` returned `false`...)

Now if none of those `echo`s executed: Are you sure you're calling the exact same function? Didn't you misspelled it or something and happen to have errors off??

Answer (score 1):

Try to detect strange invisible characters. On linux I do it with "cat -e file.php".

For all the strange-syntax-errors-because-of-one-line-in-file I try it.

Another way to test it. Remove all the lines between your $row =... and  $full_name =... and then redo your commented line (no paste, re-type it).

Comment: +1 The fact that the accepted answer works also points to this kind of thing: the parser sees line breaks that the editor does not.